# Javascript: Why use an anonymous function here?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I was browsing the JIT's code, and I saw this:

```
   var isGraph = ($type(json) == 'array');
    var ans = new Graph(this.graphOptions);
    if(!isGraph) 
        //make tree
        (function (ans, json) {
            ans.addNode(json);
            for(var i=0, ch = json.children; i<ch.length; i++) {
                ans.addAdjacence(json, ch[i]);
                arguments.callee(ans, ch[i]);
            }
        })(ans, json);
    else
        //make graph
        (function (ans, json) {
            var getNode = function(id) {
                for(var w=0; w<json.length; w++) { 
                  if(json[w].id == id) {
                    return json[w];
                  }
                }
                return undefined;
            };
```

What could be the purpose for those anonymous functions? They immediately pass out of scope, right?

Why use:

```
        (function (ans, json) {
            ans.addNode(json);
            for(var i=0, ch = json.children; i<ch.length; i++) {
                ans.addAdjacence(json, ch[i]);
                arguments.callee(ans, ch[i]);
            }
        })(ans, json);
```

instead of:

```
            ans.addNode(json);
            for(var i=0, ch = json.children; i<ch.length; i++) {
                ans.addAdjacence(json, ch[i]);
                arguments.callee(ans, ch[i]);
            }
```

Is this some super elite JS hack?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They just want to implement recursion in that small piece of code:

```
    (function (ans, json) {
        ans.addNode(json);
        for(var i=0, ch = json.children; i<ch.length; i++) {
            ans.addAdjacence(json, ch[i]);
            arguments.callee(ans, ch[i]); // <-- recursion!
        }
    })(ans, json);
```

The [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) property refers to the currently executing function, if you remove the anonymous function, it will refer to the enclosing function, and I don't think they want to invoke the whole function again.

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen `arguments.callee` used before.

Comment: You also could give the function expression an identifier. In ECMAScript 5 this is the preferred method.

Comment: @Chaos, Yes, is the preferred way, under [strict mode](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/)  `arguments.callee` is disallowed on ES5... but using named function expressions *now* can cause problems, because IE has a serious, long-standing bug, where the identifier of function expressions, lacks to the enclosing scope, actually, two function objects are created... This bug even exist on IE9 Platform Preview... Sad... See also: [Named function expressions demystified](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/)